# Excel Pivot Table - How can I return a date in the row value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table, date

I have raw data that includes hundreds of employees who have completed many different training courses and I am needing to insert a pivot table that shows the course name as the column labels, the employee name as the row/filter and rather than return a sum or count of value,  I need it to show the date that employee completed the course (which is in the raw data)  Is there a way to do this in Excel 2010 using pivot tables?  Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Pivot example]

Is this what you are maybe looking for. If it is, the assumption here is that one individual only went on a specific course once. Therefore under value field settings you can pick either sum or max or min and then format the numbers of the pivot table as dates.